# Competition Problem: Finding numbers containing "2020" from 1 to N which is a multiple of 2020 faster than O(N/2020)

Tags: python, time-complexity

I got stuck on the following competition problem:

```
Given an integer N, find the total count of positive integers from 1 to N 
that is a multiple of N and have the string "2020" in it.
```

For example: *2020*, *20200*, *1012020* are what we want to find.

I've got some sort of O(N/2020) solution, where it starts checking if it has "2020" in it from 2020, skipping 2020 every time (checks 2020,4040,then,6060,and so on).

In other words,

```
I started checking from 2020, is "2020" in it? Yes, add one to the total count.

Then check 4040, is "2020" in it? No, keep searching.
Check 6060, is "2020" i it? No, keep searching.
...
```

That got me a TLE, that is, Time Limit Exceeded error ian the competition.

So I would like to know if anyone has a better, faster solution?

Comment: Please read: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Sounds like you have an interesting challenge at hand. However, ___this is a programming question site; not a homework answering site___. Please also have a look at [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @Ivo Thanks for the note. I will try to improve this post by editing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you get stuck here's a solution

```
import math


baseInt = 2020 #This is the int you want to find within the other int
randomInt = 1012020  #This is the int you're going to count up to



def checkBaseInt(baseInt, theIteratorInt): 
    theNumString = str(theIteratorInt) #Converting to strings to find the substring
    baseIntString = str(baseInt)

    if(theNumString.find(baseIntString) == 0): #Found the substring of the baseInt into the randomint which is the iterator
        return theNumString  #Return the iterator which includes the baseInt


for i in range(baseInt, randomInt): #From your base int up to your final int
    if (checkBaseInt(baseInt, i) != None):  #If it found the desired integer within your final integer
        print(checkBaseInt(baseInt, i)) #Print the iterating integer which includes 2020, or your baseInt
```

Answer (score 0):

text = "20"
if "2020" in text:
    print(text)

You can try using the above